# What should I do to get closer to the ideal waist/chest ratio of 0.77?

Tags: strength-training

I am a 65 year-old male. Weight is 163 lbs. I exercise every day. My waist/chest ratio is 0.88. How can I get closer to the ideal ratio of 0.77?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is far too broad. We know nothing about you, so the answer would fill books in order to account for everything.

Comment: Clearly you would need to either add size to your back and chest, or remove fat from your waist, or both.  If you don't have a lot of fat around your waist, then I believe the way to reach your goal is to add muscle on your back and chest while keeping your waist size constant.  Maybe you could add some info about your amount of body fat to the question so that it could be re-opened.